# MVC: How to make multiple requests share a List of Images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a controller for retrieving images from my database, and sucessfully retrieved images with this:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    [Route("user/{userId:int}/profile", Name = "GetUserProfileImage")]
    public ActionResult UserProfileImage(int userId)
    {
        using (var imgRepo = new ImageRepository())
        {
            UserProfileImage img = imgRepo.GetUserImage(userId);
            return File(img.Image, "image/jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

The `ImageRepository` instantiates a DBContext when it's created, and disposes the DBContext when it's disposed.

Therefore I have a view displaying a list of users, and for each user I show their picture like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserRankingViewModel>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            #
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.First().Name)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RankingPosition)
            </td>
            <td>
                    <img src="@item.ImageUrl" class="img-circle img-nav">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Where `@item.ImageUrl` is an Url to `GetUserProfileImage` route. If I was to list 50 users, then 50 requests would be made to that route, and I guess 50 times the DBContext would be queried for an User Image.

For this particular case, is it possible to store a List of **UserProfileImage** in memory to avoid querying database everytime? Is this a bad practice? If Yes, why?

In my situation, there is no other application/webservice which could change database data other than this, so if a user updates their picture, I could check if is there any **in memory** picture in that List and update it, besides updating database.

Comment: You could cache the list of images using the System.Web.Caching namespace.

Comment: I probably will load images with UserRankingViewModel ( or create other view model).

Comment: You can load all images and pass them to view using `Base64` format. Also you can cache images in file system and return file result using file system.

Comment: @HaukurHaf once I cache an Image, doesn't the browser send requests for those images anymore (until the cache expires)? Or would I have to check for **cached** images in my **ImageController** action?

Comment: Don't confuse client caching (handled by the browser) and server caching (handled by the server).  I'm talking about server caching.  You could have the controller first check if the list of images exists in the Cache, if not, call the image repository to retrieve the list and add it to the cache.  Any subsequent request will then retrieve the imagelist from the cache and not hit the database.  You can have the cache expire after a set interval or just use sliding expiration and explicitly invalidate the cache yourself everytime an image is updated/deleted/added.

Comment: You can use EF cache if you use EF5 or earlier. Otherwise you can look at the [Second Level Cache for Entity Framework 6.1](https://efcache.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I think that best pratics for your IEnumerable<UserRankingViewModel> Model is to load into this model the images to display in unique query

Comment: I'm using EF6. I could load my Users **eager loading** their images (those who have one and don't have their images already cached), but this might get confused. Everytime I was to load users ranking, I'd have to discover users which already had their images cached, and make the repository load those users ignoring their images (plus loading users with non-cached images), then merge these fresh images from repo with cached ones (unleast there is another way of doing this I missed). I'm gonna read @HaukurHaf 's link.

Comment: If you separate concerns, then it will not be confusing. For example if you use file system, then the job of your action is first check if the item exists on file system return it else first simply fetch data from database and then put it on file system and return it. Also you can invalidate the whole of cache or an item of your cache when you need. For example you can create an action to recreate the file system and call it from your site control panel when you need. Or you can invalidate a user image when the image of user changes. Or you can have an schedule to invalidatethe file system.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: your solution may have performance problems. Read and write to disk is more expensive that database

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar You can simply apply client-side and server-side cache for the solution. Then they will act like static contents. Does scripts and styles and images of your site cause performance problem for the site?

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes, for site with many link (script, style, image) browser have to make one request per link. In a page where there are up to 50 links, there may be problems without correct strategy

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm developing for a customer and they aren't going to host on their servers, so I'm avoiding handling file system access, since I can't predict anything about file permissions and other possible issues (though they might have some IIS remote connection), so I decided to store any files in database, this might also turns backups easier. I think mixing Base64 + Server caching is a good solution, I'll try to implement it properly, then I share the final solution with you. Thanks for everything!!!

Comment: You can simply use `Base64` solution. Also When I talk about file system, I mean **storing images in DB** and **use file system as a cache**. and surely it will not have permission issues, because you save image cache for example in `/Content/UserImages` path of your site. And you can simply create the folder and files at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load all images into your model as byte64, and show directly in view.
In your code, what is UserProfileImage? what king for UserProfileImage.Image?

You can try;

```
class UserRankingViewModel
{
    ... ...
    public string ImageBase64 {get;set;}
}

class yourController: Controller
{
    public IActionResult YourMethodForLoadUserRunk()
    {
        .... ....
        //here you can load image from dbcontext (memorystream for ex)
        //and convert to array
        var user = new UserRankingViewModel();
        var string64 = Convert.ToBase64String(yourimage.ToArray());
        user.ImageBase64 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", string64);
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

So in your View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RankingPosition)
        </td>
        <td>
                <img src="@item.ImageBase64" class="img-circle img-nav">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: You can improve my solution using server cache (example System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache) and save users data for your ranking view